# Parse Data won't export

Tags: json, parsing, export

I am trying to export my User data on Parse and it is just hanging there. All it says is "Waiting to Begin" with a bunch of unfilled dots. Usually I receive my data in seconds. Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: Looks like currently that is a recognized bug https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/549

Comment: Did you end up finding any solution?

Comment: What's up with the issue? We are doing our final migration and stucked. Did you manage?

Comment: Same here ... anybody has a solution for this. 'Waiting to begin' for almost a day now!!